# Best way to split strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to parse an array of strings, such as

```
const example = [
'Terms and Conditions',
'5. Terms and Conditions Title (dot at the end). Some general info here.',
'5.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
'6. Terms and Conditions Title ends with semi-column now: Some general info here.',
'6.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
];
```

How I want to render it (React)

**Terms and Conditions**

- 5. **Terms and Conditions Title (dot at the end).** Some general info here.

     - 5.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.
- 6. **Terms and Conditions Title ends with semi-column now:** Some general info here.

     - 6.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.

What I've done so far:
(ignore slice fn)

```
return (
<div>
  {_.slice(_.map(example, (item, index) => {
    const key = index;
    if (index === 0) { // First text
      return (<h1 key={key}>{item}</h1>);
    }
    if (item === '') {
      return (<br key={key} />);
    }
    if ((/^(\d|\d\d)\. /).test(item)) { // "5. Heading"
      const list = _.split(item, / \.|:/, 2);
      const bold = _.size(list) === 2 ? list[0] : item;
      const normal = _.size(list) === 2 ? list[1] : '';
      return [
        <span className="bold" key={`bold-${key}`}>{bold}</span>,
        <p className="normal"  key={`normal-${key}`}>{normal}</p>,
      ];
    }
    return (<p className="normal" key={key}>{item}</p>);
  }), startIndex, !_.isNil(endIndex) ? endIndex : _.size(example))}
</div>
```

);

However, I need a better way of determing if text should be split (bold text and normal), and better way of splitting it.

Issue: My code currently does not _.split the text that ends with '.' or ':', instead I am left with an entire string of

```
'5. Terms and Conditions Title (dot at the end). Some general info here.' <- BOLD.
```

So the issues lies here (lodash function):

```
_.split(item, / \.|:/, 2);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML of the expected output? Also, will you have more nesting like `5.1.1`?

Comment: You can use Markdown

Comment: the html output doesn't really matter here, as I simply need to split the '5. hello. wow' into -> ['5. hello.', 'wow'], and can't seem to figure the correct regex for that. (ends with a dot or ":")

Comment: also, no more nesting, and if there will be I wouldn't need to put anything to bold anymore, so no issues there

Comment: No way to receive the data in another format? All the solutions I can think of are messy, maybe you should work with your API / data source?

Comment: This comes wrong a .doc/.docx, no API there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've solved it. Took me some time.

Basically the correct regex to do this job is:

**5. Title.** Other stuff

```
/^[\d|\d\d]\.\s[A-Z].*?[.!?:]/
```

Also if I want to split it into 3 strings

5. **Title.** Other stuff

   (['5.', 'Title', 'Other stuff'])

The regex could be

```
/^(\d|\d\d)\.\s[A-Z].*?[.!?:]/
```

But due to how lodash split works, I had to come up with a different solution:

```
    if ((/^(\d|\d\d)\. /).test(item)) { // "5. Heading"
  const list = _.compact(_.split(item, /\.|:/, 3)); // removing [''] -> [], 3 items
  if (_.size(list) !== 3) { // if didn't get 3 items. something went wrong (bad text)
    return (<p key={`normal-${key}`}>{item}</p>);
  }
  const bullet = list[0];
  const bold = list[1];
  const normal = list[2];
  return [
    <span className="bullet" key={`bullet-${key}`} style={{ fontWeight: 400 }}>{`${bullet}.`}</span>,
    <span className="bold" key={`bold-${key}`} style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>{`${bold}.`}</span>,
    <span className="normal" key={`normal-${key}`} style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>{normal}</span>,
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this flatten array into a nested one, then, it will be easy to iterate each depth, and render the proper layout.

```js
const example = [
  'Terms and Conditions',
  '5. Terms and Conditions Title (dot at the end). Some general info here.',
  '5.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
  '5.2. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
  '6. Terms and Conditions Title ends with semi-column now: Some general info here.',
  '6.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
];

function getChildrenAtDepth(depth, nestedObj) {
  let current = nestedObj[nestedObj.length - 1].children;

  for (i = 0; i < depth - 1; i++) {
    current = current[current.length - 1].children;
  }

  return current

}

const nestedData = example.reduce((result, currentLine) => {
  const matches = currentLine.match(/^(\d+\.?)+\s/);

  if (matches) {
    const depth = matches[0].split('.').length - 1;

    const children = getChildrenAtDepth(depth, result);
    children.push({
      title: currentLine,
      children: []
    })
  } else {
    result.push({
      title: currentLine,
      children: []
    })

  }

  return result;
}, []);


var Comp = function Comp(_ref) {
  var data = _ref.data;
  var depth = _ref.depth;
  return React.createElement("ul", {
    className: 'depth-' + depth
  }, data.map(function(header) {
    return React.createElement("li", null, header.title, header.children.length > 0 && React.createElement(Comp, {
      data: header.children,
      depth: depth + 1
    }));
  }));
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Comp, {
  data: nestedData,
  depth: 0
}), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.depth-0>li {
  font-size: 1.44rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

ul.depth-1>li {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

ul.depth-2>li {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

This snippet will generate

```js
[{
  title: 'Terms and Conditions',
  children: [{
    title: '5. Terms and Conditions Title (dot at the end). Some general info here.',
    children: [{
      title: '5.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
      children: []
    }, {
      title: '5.2. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
      children: []
    }]
  }, {
    title: '6. Terms and Conditions Title ends with semi-column now: Some general info here.',
    children: [{
      title: '6.1. Sub-section title. Some more info here.',
      children: []
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Well, this is a good way to nest it, indeed. Altought nesting isn't necessary in my case it can be on the same level, all that was needed was to have children.title string split into ['5.', 'Title.', 'Remaining content'] so I could render them as <span>5.</span><span bold>Title.</span><span>Remaining content</span>

Comment: It become nested because of the default browser styles, you can change it, and add you styles dependant on depth, I've updated my example

Comment: ul.depth-0>li font-weight: 600; - as an option

Comment: You can style it as you wanna using css